# Kriging Interpolation

Tags: r, kriging

Hi i want to plot a map of Argentina with certain reports of hail using the interpolation of Kriging but i cant in R or python. Can anybody help me?

Regarding the reports, these come in the following format:

[image]

Thank you!

I tried this using chatgpt to help me:

```
library(gstat)
library(sp)

# Cargar el archivo CSV con los datos de reportes de granizo

datos <- read.csv("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Agus/FACULTAD/Tesis/SI - NO ROMINA.csv", nrows = 7089)  # Reemplaza con la ubicación y nombre de tu archivo CSV

# Convertir las columnas de Latitud y Longitud a formato numérico

datos$Latitud <- as.numeric(as.character(datos$Latitud))
datos$Longitud <- as.numeric(as.character(datos$Longitud))

Crear un objeto SpatialPoints con los datos de latitud y longitud

datos_sp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(
coords = datos[, c("Longitud", "Latitud")],
data = datos,
proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
)

# Crear una cuadrícula regular para la predicción

grd <- expand.grid(
Longitud = seq(min(datos$Longitud, na.rm = TRUE), max(datos$Longitud, na.rm = TRUE), length.out = 100),
Latitud = seq(min(datos$Latitud, na.rm = TRUE), max(datos$Latitud, na.rm = TRUE), length.out = 100)
)
grd_sp <- SpatialPoints(coords = grd, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# Realizar la interpolación mediante Kriging

kriged <- krige(rep(1, nrow(datos_sp)) ~ 1, datos_sp, grd_sp)

# Obtener los valores predichos para cada punto de la grilla

predicted_values <- vector("numeric", length = nrow(grd))
for (i in 1:nrow(grd)) {
predicted_values[i] <- krige(rep(1, nrow(datos_sp)) ~ 1, datos_sp, grd_sp[i, ])$predictions
}

# Crear una matriz con los valores predichos

kriged_values <- matrix(predicted_values, nrow = 100)

# Graficar el mapa de interpolación de Kriging

par(mar = c(1, 1, 1, 1)) # Ajustar los márgenes si es necesario
image(
x = seq(min(datos$Longitud, na.rm = TRUE), max(datos$Longitud, na.rm = TRUE), length.out = 100),
y = seq(min(datos$Latitud, na.rm = TRUE), max(datos$Latitud, na.rm = TRUE), length.out = 100),
z = kriged_values,
col = terrain.colors(50),
main = "Mapa de Interpolación de Kriging"
)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what problems you run into doing this?

Comment: Basically I can't get any results, I can't get any graphs. I don't quite understand how interpolation works and what results I have to have to "put it in"

Comment: I would suggest reading a tutorial on [kriging](https://rpubs.com/nabilabd/118172). That's likely to be more helpful in understanding what you need to do. `I don't quite understand how interpolation works and what results I have to have to "put it in"` Can you describe your dataset? In order to use kriging, you must have latitude, longitude, and some dependent variable. Do you have this?

Comment: Since version 2.0 (2019) `gstat` also supports `sf` and `stars` packages for vector and raster data , I'd switch my workflow to those packages unless there's a solid reason to keep using `sp`.  https://r-spatial.org/book/12-Interpolation.html walks you through the interpolation process, it will also help you to change your question so it would be more detailed and focused (i.e. identify the problematic step between loading input data and plotting output, present the problem in way that it's reproducible for others).